# Looking for fast cross-platform desktop sharing application

Tags: vpn, remote, vnc, desktop, share

I'm looking for a simple, cross-platform, fast, and secure way to share the desktop of a local machine with other people.  For example, if co-worker working remotely shares their desktop, I'd be able to view it from the office.

I've used VNC in the past, and it's great for sharing desktops on the same network, but don't know how well it will work to connect to users outside of the network.

Something that looks interesting is screenleap, but it seems great, but kinda slow.
http://www.screenleap.com/

Another option that I'm trying to find information about is setting up a simple VPN, so the remote users will be on the same network as the local users.  A lot of the VPN options that I've looked at seem non-trivial to setup.

I'm hoping to find a solution that will work on Linux, Mac, and Windows.  And, the client users don't all have a technical background, so I was hoping to find something easy enough to use.

What do you all use to solve the problem of sharing desktops with your co-workers?  Thank you for considering my question.

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off topic per the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx), I've used it for years and they have many different settings depending on needs (Meetings, File Shareing, etc.)

Hope this helps and DFTBA. :)